# Indy 10 compilation fails with FASTMM compiler directive enabled

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-7, indy, indy10

I'm using Delphi 7. I downloaded the latest version of Indy (10.5462) from Fulgan's page yesterday.

There is a batch file (Full_d7.bat) which normally compiles Indy successfully.

Now if I DEFINE USE_FASTMM4 in IdCompilerDefines.inc in Core, Protocols and System directory, the following error is given back on compilation:

```
IdGlobal.pas(2229) Error: Declaration of 'GetBytes' differs from declaration in
interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
IdGlobal.pas(2229) Error: Declaration of 'GetCharCount' differs from declaration
 in interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
IdGlobal.pas(2229) Error: Declaration of 'GetChars' differs from declaration in
interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
IdGlobal.pas(2229) Error: Declaration of 'GetChars' differs from declaration in
interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
IdGlobal.pas(2229) Error: Declaration of 'GetChars' differs from declaration in
interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
IdGlobal.pas(2229) Error: Declaration of 'GetString' differs from declaration in
 interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
IdGlobal.pas(3500) Error: Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Integer'
IdGlobal.pas(3502) Error: Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Integer'
IdGlobal.pas(3527) Error: Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char'
IdGlobal.pas(3592) Error: Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Byte'
IdGlobal.pas(3594) Error: Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Byte'
IdGlobal.pas(3617) Error: Incompatible types
IdGlobal.pas(3620) Error: Incompatible types: 'Word' and 'Char'
IdGlobal.pas(3663) Error: Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Byte'
IdGlobal.pas(3665) Error: Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Byte'
IdGlobal.pas(3687) Error: Incompatible types: 'Word' and 'Char'
```

Is this a bug in the D7 edition or I'm missing something? Is there something maybe that needs to be defined as well in the config file when using FastMM?

Comment: Those kind of errors imply that FastMM is probably redeclaring some basic data types that Indy uses, like `PByte`, etc. Indy specifies FastMM in the `uses` clause of the `implementation` section, not in the `interface` section, so any redeclarations of those types would take priority, thus causing the `interface` and `implementation` to differ. I'll have to look at what FastMM is actually doing and adjust Indy accordingly.

Comment: One more interesting issue: The path to FastMM.dcu is in the Library/Browsing paths in Delphi7. But when I run Full_d7.bat it says FastMM.dcu can't be found. Copying the file to Core, Protocols and Sytem directory solves the problem, but this isn't very elegant.

Comment: the IDE's search paths don't apply to command-line compiling. You will have to make sure FastMM is in the environment's `%PATH%`. You could always just ignore the batch file and open/compile/install the projects from within the IDE instead.

Answer (score 0):

FastMM declares its own version of several Delphi native data types (`Native(U)Int`, `(U)IntPtr`, etc) when supporting older compilers that do not have those types available.

However, it is *also* declaring `PByte` in all Delphi versions prior to D2009, which it should NOT be doing (since `PByte` is available in the RTL's `System` unit going all the way back to at least Delphi 5).  That redeclaration of `PByte` is interfering with Indy's use of `PByte` in the `IdGlobal` unit - but only in Delphi versions prior to D2006 (as Indy does not use FastMM directly in later Delphi versions).

I have checked in a patch for Indy to address this (SVN rev 5463), and [filed a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/fastmm/bugs/69/) with FastMM.